# Joining two large tables using a calculated model in AppMaker

Tags: sql, google-app-maker

I have two SQL datasources in Google AppMaker. Both will have tens of thousands of records in them:

LastLogins:

```
+-------------------+-----------+
|       Email       | LastLogin |
+-------------------+-----------+
| email@domain.com  | 1/1/2019  |
| email2@domain.com | 12/1/2018 |
+-------------------+-----------+
```

and Licenses:

```
+------------------+---------+------------+
|      Email       |  SkuID  |  SkuName   |
+------------------+---------+------------+
| email@domain.com | 1001001 | Enterprise |
| email2@domain.com| 1001001 | Basic      |
+------------------+---------+------------+
```

I'd like to join the tables to create a calculated datasource with this data:

```
+------------------+---------+------------+-----------+
|      Email       |  SkuID  |  SkuName   | LastLogin |
+------------------+---------+------------+-----------+
| email@email.com  | 1001001 | Enterprise | 1/1/2019  |
| email2@email.com | 1001001 | Basic      | 12/1/2018 |
+------------------+---------+------------+-----------+
```

I tried a few different `join` commands but none worked. This is my current iteration:

```
select 
    m.Email,
    m.SkuID,
    m.SkuName,
    l.Email,
    l.LastLogin
from Licenses m ,LastLogins l
full join LastLogins on Licenses.Email = LastLogins.Email
```

The error I get is;

> Exception: Malformed SQL. More information: Error with SQL statement:
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'full join LastLogins on Licenses.Email = LastLogins.Email LIMIT
>   26' at line 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, but your syntax to JOIN tables is wrong.

The syntax is :

```
FROM <table1> as <alias1>
INNER JOIN <table2> as <alias2> ON ...
```

Try :

```
select 
    m.Email,
    m.SkuID,
    m.SkuName,
    l.LastLogin
from Licenses as m
inner join LastLogins as l on l.Email = m.Email
```